# Best Way to handle Repeat thing with MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php

I have two tables in database called
tbl_rotator_urls and tbl_rotators_data

tbl_rotator_urls contains urls and tbl_rotators_data contains urls visit history with ip address.

I am redirecting users based on url position. on first visit user getting redirected on first position url, on second visit user getting redirected on second position url and so on.

for above thing, I am checking table like this and making query like below

```
 $visited_urls=-1;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT link_id 
                            FROM tbl_rotators_data 
                            WHERE rotator_id = ? 
                            AND link_id !=0 
                            AND ip=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('is',$rotator_id,$ip);
    $stmt->execute();
    $visited_result = $stmt->get_result();
    $total_visited_urls = $visited_result->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    $visited_array = array();
    if($total_visited_urls>0){
        while($visited_row=mysqli_fetch_array($visited_result)){
           $visited_array[] = $visited_row['link_id'];
        }
        if(sizeof($visited_array)>0){
          $visited_urls = implode(',', $visited_array); 
          
        }else{
           $visited_urls=-1; 
        }
        
    }
```

so its giving me comma seperated list of users visited url

which I am using like below for get next remain url

```
 //select URL which is not visited by USER
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT u.url_id,u.url_url,
                            FROM tbl_rotator_urls u 
                                LEFT JOIN tbl_rotators_data l ON u.url_id=l.link_id 
                            WHERE u.rotator_id = ? 
                            AND u.url_id NOT IN($visited_urls) 
                            AND url_status=0 
                            GROUP BY u.url_id 
                            ORDER BY $orderby ASC");
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$rotator_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $url_result = $stmt->get_result();
    $total_urls = $url_result->num_rows;
    if($total_urls== 0){
        // USER have visited all URLS SO set $visited_urls=-1; SO it can get URL again
        $visited_urls=-1;   //this is doubtful point, I should do something else or more with this but no idea
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT u.url_id,u.url_url,
                                FROM tbl_rotator_urls u 
                                    LEFT JOIN tbl_rotators_data l ON u.url_id=l.link_id 
                                WHERE u.rotator_id = ? 
                                AND u.url_id NOT IN($visited_urls) 
                                AND url_status=0 
                                GROUP BY u.url_id 
                                ORDER BY $orderby ASC");
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$rotator_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $url_result = $stmt->get_result();
        $total_urls = $url_result->num_rows; 
    
    }
    
    ..... CONTINUE MY CODE FOR REDIRECT
```

in above function if user have visited all urls, I am setting $visited_urls=-1 so I am able to get URL, but on all visit, I am getting same URL, instead I want one by one like below

for example I have 5 urls, I want repeat like

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Database Table information

tbl_rotator_urls structure like below

```
url_id, url_name, url_url
```

tbl_rotators_data structure like below

```
rid, link_id,rotator_id, ip,timestamp
```

I have no idea how I can put sample data here, so I have written in excel and put image here

**SAMPLE DATA IMAGE**:

[image]

I am learning PHP and struggling from last two hours for achieve my goal but not getting idea how I can do it. Let me know if any expert here can help me for same.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some sample data for these 2 tables

Comment: If you are going to show us the schema for a table, its better to do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: `on all visit, I am getting same URL`...where exactly? I don't see any code which actually gets data from your query, it only counts the rows. The question is a bit unclear and some code appears to be missing. Please provide a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have added sample data image

Comment: @ADyson First query is for make comma seperated URL list which is user have visited before then I am using that on next query to exclude that URL

Comment: `I have no idea how I can put sample data here`...copy and paste?? More seriously, read this from our Meta site: [How can I create a table in a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post). Also read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) - it applies just as much to to data as to code.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this code work

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT u.url_id,u.url_url,
                        FROM tbl_rotator_urls u 
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_rotators_data l ON u.url_id=l.link_id 
                        WHERE u.rotator_id = ? 
                        AND u.url_id NOT IN(
                            SELECT link_id 
                            FROM tbl_rotators_data 
                            WHERE rotator_id = ? 
                            AND link_id !=0 
                            AND ip=?
                        ) 
                        AND url_status=0 
                        GROUP BY u.url_id 
                        ORDER BY $orderby ASC");
$stmt->bind_param(1 ,$rotator_id);
$stmt->bind_param(2 ,$rotator_id);
$stmt->bind_param(3 ,$ip);
$stmt->execute();
$url_result = $stmt->get_results(); // array of database results
```